# How to get most common value in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this in SQL server

```
UsageTime        Website

10:45:08       yahoo.co.uk

10:24:06       msn.co.uk

09:45:08       lycos.co.uk
```

I need to GET something like this

```
BusiestHour   NoOfWebsitesVisited
10:00         2
```

I have tried this

```
SELECT TOP 3  UsageTime as BusiestHour, COUNT(Website) FROM  NoOfWebsitesVisited
GROUP BY BusiestHour
```

But this isn't quite right. It doesn't check the whole hour, just a particular value.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :) thanks

Comment: Use `datepart(h, UsageTime)` to get the hour part of the date - you can then build a more useful expression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 3   
       DATEPART(HOUR,UsageTime) as BusiestHour, 
       COUNT(Website) FROM  NoOfWebsitesVisited
GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR,UsageTime)
ORDER BY NoOfWebsitesVisited DESC;
```

Maybe you want sonething like:

```
SELECT TOP 3 WITH TIES
       DATEPART(HOUR,UsageTime) as BusiestHour, 
       COUNT(Website) FROM  NoOfWebsitesVisited
GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR,UsageTime)
ORDER BY NoOfWebsitesVisited DESC;
```